# Spring Boot ADFS SAML Request Issues

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I have been tasked with taking an existing Java Web application, using JSP, and add in Multi-factor authentication. We are using Microsoft ADFS. The trust relationship setup by our administrator looks like this:

[image: ADFS Trust Relationship]

I've tried using open source helper libraries such as [Coveo/saml-client](https://github.com/coveo/saml-client) and [Onelogin/java-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml). It may have been my understanding, but both proved to not work so well. No errors in the code, just when an error when submitting my request.

We have folks in Brazil who have successfully implemented the same, but they developed their application using Spring Boot and [ulisesbocchio/spring-boot-security-saml](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/spring-boot-security-saml). So I am trying to replicate that effort.

Using one of the sample applications from ulisesbocchio/spring-boot-security-saml and some of the configuration from our Brazil team, I have a spring boot application, but I am still receiving the same bland, generic ADFS error:

[image: ADFS Error]

My AuthNRequest, as generated from the ulisesbocchio/spring-boot-security-saml is:

[image: AuthNRequest]

I think the error is caused by ADFS not finding the trust when I am using the Entity ID, or Relying Party Identifier, `Mixing`. I've also tried using `http://machine name/Mixing` with the same error.

Maybe this is not the issue, and if that is the case, then I have no idea where to look next.

Please help me figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: You need to examine the ADFS [logs](https://support.robinpowered.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005014143-How-to-check-ADFS-logs-for-SAML-logins) for a more meaningful error message. There are examples of connecting ADFS to spring-security-saml: [one](https://github.com/choonchernlim/spring-security-adfs-saml2) [two](https://github.com/deeprot/spring-saml-adfs)

Comment: The value of the Issuer in the SAML AuthnRequest is the entityID of the SAML Service Provider. This needs to be set as identifier. If there is still an issue on ADFS side you need to inspect the logs as proposed.

Comment: identigral and Bernhard Thalmayr, thank you for your responses. I will have to talk with our admin about the log files as I do not have access.